# How can I test paypal micropayments in the paypal sandbox?

Tags: paypal, sandbox

Is there a way to test paypal micropayments in the sandbox?  I can see where to upgrade the test account to paypal payments pro. But i don't see one for micropayments.  I am trying to verify smaller transactions.

Answer (score 0):

While it does not make much sense to see the pricing of sandbox transactions change, you can contact MTS under paypal.com/mts
give them the e-mail address of the sandbox merchant account you want to enable Micro Payments for and they should be able to activate it for that account.